# How to get the latest jar file in Sonatype Nexus when trying to do build in Maven inside of Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, maven-3, nexus

all

There are two questions actually.

1. I'm now using Sonatype Nexus 2.11.3-01 as my private repository server. However, logged in with admin, I found that the Artifact Upload tab is missing in default Snapshots repository. I'm not sure why as this tab is in Releases or 3rd party. Is this a defect or am I missing something when doing setting in Nexus? This will cause 401 error when trying to deploy the jar file to Snapshots repository -- Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> (I checked my setting for credentials and they are all correct.)
2. I have a customized jar file and I would like to put it into Snapshots repository. But when using Maven to upload the snapshot jar into Nexus, it will add a timestamp in the file name. Based on my search in Maven 3 it drop the support to remove the timestamp in snapshots. So is it possible to retrieve the latest jar in Nexus from POM file?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your full settings.xml file (of course without the passwords ;-))

Answer (score 0):

The `Upload` tab in a SNAPSHOT repository does usually make no sense cause a SNAPSHOT repository is intended for SNAPSHOT's and not for 3rd Party artifacts which will usually uploaded once and used over a longer time.
The `Snapshot` repository will be used by Maven/Gradle etc. to upload SNAPSHOTs during the development.
If you have a customized JAR which i assume will not change that often should be put it into 3rdParty repository instead of SNAPSHOT.
A SNAPSHOT repository is a storage for a shorter time period which should be cleaned up at least after creating a release of your artifact (project in Maven).

If you put something like `Name-1.0-SNAPSHOT` into Nexus SNAPSHOT repository the artifacts are internally named like `Name-1.0-20150701-203434-1.jar` this is made by Nexus and not by Maven.

If you like to get the latest SNAPSHOT state from the nexus repository you have to use `mvn -U ...` on maven command line (If you like to change the default behaviour you can change that by [configuring in your settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-settings/settings.html#class_repository)).